# Azure Application Gateway - single parent domain for multiple web applications

Tags: azure, gateway

I am trying to setup one parent domain (app.mydomain.com) for front for 2 web apps in the backend.
mail.mydomain.com and module.mydomain.com. I have implement path based routing. I need to routing to work so

app.mydomain.com/* **points** module1.mydomain.com

app.mydomain.com/module2/* **points** module2.mydomain.com/

Routing seems to work, however when browsing module2, it css and js are not loaded and the site doesnt work. accessing module2 directly works normally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you routing rules to change your URL?
Since you are using App Gateway, the URL that your backend is seeing is (app.mydomain.com) instead of module2.mydomain.com.

So, maybe when you’re using the AppGateway, your backend is looking for a CSS into the wrong path…